# Match group of files, excluding one specific file, in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell, glob

I have bunch of files having the following names: `text.sh`, `text`, `text.1`, `text.2` etc. How can I refer to all these files, except `text.sh`, in my bash script? I tried to use `text*` but it also matches `text.sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable extended globbing and use an exclusion list.

```
shopt -s extglob
echo text!(.sh)
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback. This almost worked. However this does not include file `test`.

Comment: This answer doesn't include `test` because the `.` is outside of the exclusion "grouping." It should be `text!(.sh)`, no?

Comment: @Mark I made that change, but now it will also include `text1` with no `.`.  Is that OK?

Answer (score 2):

@Barmar's answer is essentially the  same as mine, but it's generally bad practice to iterate over the output of `ls` in a shell script. There are many different options for iteration, one is a for loop:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in text!(.sh) ; do ... ; done
```

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164025/exclude-one-pattern-from-glob-match

Comment: I didn't mean that he should iterate over the `ls` output, it's just a way to see what was matched. I changed it to `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command, will appear the files that does NOT match with `text.sh`:

```
 ls -l !(text.sh)
```

This will be your output:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 sep 13 10:44 text
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 sep 13 10:45 text.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 sep 13 10:45 text.2
```

By the way, another solution, more complex:

```
  ls -l !(text.sh|!(text?(.)*));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
for file in text*; do
    [[ $file == 'test.sh' ]] && continue
    # Processing
done
```

This avoids all the edge cases encountered with extended globs. If you want it to be portable to any POSIX shell, you could use `[ ]` instead:

```
for file in text*; do
    [ "$file" = 'test.sh' ] && continue
    # Processing
done
```